# Is it possible for any creature to stay on an altostratus cloud without falling down? what are its limits?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, atmosphere

I am working on a story. i want to know if is it possible for creatures like snake, eagle, vulture to stay on an altostratus cloud without falling down. if possible the limits on how much force and pressure it can withstand.

[image: types of clouds chart]
[image]

Altostratus clouds are mid-level, gray or blue-gray clouds that usually covers the whole sky. The Sun or moon may shine through an altostratus cloud, but will appear watery or fuzzy. If you see altostratus clouds, a storm with continuous rain or snow might be on its way. Occasionally, rain falls from an altostratus cloud. If the rain hits the ground, then the cloud has become a nimbostratus.

***Thanks for your answers***

Comment: What do you mean with "stay on"? Stay above it, or onto it like we stay on the floor?

Comment: Peaceman, I want the snakes up on your clouds.  With real clouds and real snakes it is hard to see how it could work.  Check out the copious talk of "floating islands" on the stack.  Maybe one of these schemes could work?  Maybe you will come back with another questions refining the floating islands for your world?  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=floating+islands

Answer (score 6):

A cloud is like a fog or a mist. You can actually be inside one and feel it on your skin if you climb a mountain in some places. So no animal can rest atop one - no animal has a density even close to a cloud's.

[Some microorganisms are able to thrive up there](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2013/01/microbes-survive-and-maybe-thrive-high-atmosphere), but they don't need the clouds for physical support.

Comment: Add to this that if a creature is large enough to be considered ‘supported’ by the cloud it’s also large enough to act as a nucleation site for a raindrop, leading to the cloud descending downwards very rapidly.

Answer (score 2):

A cloud is a volume of water vapour in a high enough concentration that it refracts and reflects light as if it had a surface, which it does not. The volume of the cloud is air with more water vapour than the air surrounding it ... so there is no surface that anything could use to resist gravity. So, no, your creatures cannot stay supported on an altostratus cloud.